# Data from the form is not inserted in to user table

Tags: python, django

I am trying to create signup form adding email field in django from base class UserCreationForm. The code goes as

**form.py**

```
class ussignup(UserCreationForm):

  email=forms.EmailField()

  class Meta:
    model=User
    fields=('username','email','password1','password2')

  def save(self, commit=True):
        user = super(UserCreationForm, self).save(commit=False)
        user.email=(self.cleaned_data["email"])
        if commit:
            user.save()
        return user
```

**view.py**

```
def signup(request):
    if request.method=='POST':
        form=ussignup(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/accounts/rgsuc')

    args={}
    args.update(csrf(request))
    args['form']=ussignup()
    return render_to_response('register.html',args)
```

**urls.py**

```
 url(r'^accounts/signup',signup),
```

**Error**
   output shows the email field . however it is neither validating the required field nor the email field data is inserted to the user database table
    I tried through this video tutorial [here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xaPHSlTmg1s&list=PLxxA5z-8B2xk4szCgFmgonNcCboyNneMD)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your view, you are doing

```
form=signup(request.POST)
```

instead it should be

```
form=ussignup(request.POST)
```

i.e use form class name to instantiate the form.

Also, its better to show form errors if any when its not valid, you can do that by updating your code as

```
def signup(request):
    if request.method=='POST':
        form=ussignup(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/accounts/rgsuc')
    else:
        form=ussignup()
    args={}
    args.update(csrf(request))
    args['form']=form
    return render_to_response('register.html',args)
```

Comment: yes, the user email is reflected in User database. however I have email field to required =True but it doesnot prompt "this field is required " when i leave the email blank but it redirects to the same page with empty fields

Comment: @LaxmiKadariya, have you updated the code as I said to show the errors? If so update the question with new code.

Comment: @Roshan Yes I have updated the code. When I enter the  two mismatched password it doesnot prompt password mismatch. but redirects to initial blank form. It doesnot automatically handle the validation and errors?

Comment: yes, yes I got it.Thanks .I used the above given code and it shows the error message. Thanks a lot